The pin configuration of an RJ45 network connector Pulse J0G-0001NL
I have a few questions about whether I have pulled the right one for this RJ45 connector.
It's a Pulse J0G-0001NL and the pin configuration is below.

But note that if you look at the pattern, you will see that the first digit is an 8 on the plus side. It is lower than the number 9 on minus.
But if we look at the number 3 which is plus, but the number 2 is minus. So vice versa.
When I pulled my differential pairs, I had to pull some from below. Then I wonder if it really has to be like this? I think this is weird, because usually everyone has the same symmetry, but here it's a different symmetry. So what is right here?



I see no reason to doubt the datasheet here. It is pretty unambiguous and well described. Ethernet pairs are not really symmetric mapped out anyway - the 4/5 pair is in the middle of the 3/6 pair on jack side, but are not on the PCB side.
There is no reason to assume symmetry after all the magnetics in the connector. That they have chosen mirror symmetry is just their design choice. Molex use the same pin-out for the 85793 series too.
This is the fully functional escape routing we have used previously on an J0G-0009NL connector which is in the same series and same datasheet as the J0G-0001NL using the same pin numbering.
It looks basically the same as yours, except all my pairs come out in the opposite direction, but we still have the same lack of symmetry. I clearly just needed the P/N of each pair opposite to you.


so I can use my routing?

It looks reasonable. I would perhaps try and avoid the pair running between pins 3/4 but is probably fine. Notice that mine is basically the mirror image of yours, so where I run the 2/3 pair around pin 1 to avoid going through the middle, your case it would be running 4/5 around pin 6.
